# How to write complex constraints in cvxpy?

Tags: python, cvxpy

I am trying to write a portfolio optimization problem using cvxpy.

```
initial_weights = [0.045, 0.035, 0.024, 0.028...]
rets = (np.log(data/data.shift(1))
w = cvx.Variable(38)
ret = np.sum(rets.mean()*w)*252
prob = cvx.Problem(cvx.Maximize(ret), [cvx.sum_entries(w)==1, w>0.02, w<0.06])
result = prob.solve()
```

After solving, w.value is of the form [[0.02], [0.02], [0.04]...]

I want to add a constraint that works something like this:

```
for i in range(len(initial_weights)):
    abs(initial_weights[i]-w[1][i])>0.005
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to include this in the constraints?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add constraints in a for loop, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706519/how-to-write-several-constraint-in-cvxpy) seems to provide the solution.

I am also surprised that the value being returned is an array of arrays, instead of an array of values. If you ensure that the dimension of `rets.mean()` is correct, then `w` should be a simple array with 38 values. In that case, your constraint simplifies to
`abs(initial_weights-w)>0.005`

Comment: How do I make the value being returned an array of values?

Comment: In this example on the documentation, the default result is array of values - https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/least_squares.html.
You can try replicating the example and if you obtain the array correctly, then the only place where I think your code would cause a change is in the dimension of `rets.mean()`. What's the size of `rets.mean()`?

Comment: rets.mean is a pandas data frame with 35 rows

Comment: That's likely the reason for the shape of your `w`. Try converting `rets.mean()` to an array of values. `rets.mean().values()` might help.